# Regular Expression for any string which takes all the characters prior to .pdf

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Can any one give the regular expression for checking a string prior to `.pdf`

For example: I want the text `angular` from the string `angular.pdf#2345` or `angular.pdfthis`.

Comment: Any effort yourself in resolving this?

Comment: Yeah i have tried but got stuck in finding if there will be .pdf twice in the same string.
But now, got the alternate as substring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression with a positive lookahead.

```
/.*(?=\.pdf)/
```

```js
console.log('angular.pdf#2345'.match(/.*(?=\.pdf)/));
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

`(.*)\.pdf.*`

The first matching group will contain the string prior to `.pdf`.

See this [example](https://regex101.com/r/oP6sY7/1).

Answer (score 1):

Seems your example clarifies what you really want.

**str.substring(0,str.indexOf(".pdf"))**

Comment: Remove the `+1`? This will give you "angular."

Comment: No, you cannot. If you want the very last character before '.' to also be included, you have to specify end index as the one past what you need as end index.

Comment: Try it in your console. it will give you "angular." (note the dot).

Comment: I am so sorry.  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp Sue them :P Plus I thought since that was the way it worked in Java.

Comment: Hehe. I always avoid that website. Get a better source like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/